# Define default prop in a separate js file

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to define default props in a separate js file instead of main js.
Now it's defined in the functionalComponent.js file
functionalComponent.defaultProps = {
  quantity: 0,
  maxLimit: 5,
  minLimit: 0
};

I want to define it in separate file and use it in my functionalComponent.js

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate js file, define your default props in it as object and export them.
import the same file into your functionalComponent.js, extract and assign to your default props.

```
App.js
----------
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import defaultProps from "./common/defaultProps";

function App(props) {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">Count {props.count}</header>
        </div>
    );
}
App.defaultProps = defaultProps["App"];
export default App;

defaultProps.js
------------------
const defaultProps = {
    App: { count: 0 }
};

export default defaultProps;
```